# removeChild "Node was not found" - cant work it out

Tags: javascript

Here is the code below I am using the remove cells (which have been selected) from a table. It works some of the time, but then other times it brings up a "Node was not found"  code:

> "8" (NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_FOUND_ERR)

Can't seem to figure how to do it. Any help would be great.

```
var p = document.getElementById('tableTr');
while(selectTag=document.getElementsByClassName('tagSelected')) {
    if(!selectTag[0]) {
        break;
    }
    if(selectTag[0].className=="tagSelected")
        var c =selectTag[0];
        p.removeChild(c);
    }
}
```

I have a PHP script that populates the table and thats about it to my HTML:

```
<div id="uploadTag">
    <table class="tagBlock" id="tableTag" cellspacing="5px;">

        <?php 

        $uploadlist=substr($uploadlists, 0, -1);
        $uploadList=explode(";",$uploadlist);
        $i=0;
        foreach($uploadList as $key=>$list){
            if($i==0)
            { ?>    
                <tr id="tableTr"> 
            <?php } 

            $i++; $up="up".($key+1); 
            $imageext = substr(strrchr($list, '.'), 1);
            $val=$list;
            if ($imageext=='png' || $imageext=='bmp' || $imageext=='gif' || $imageext=='tif' || $imageext=='jpg')
            {
                $val="<image>";
            }


                ?><td id="<?php echo $up; ?>" class="tagBlock" title="<?php echo $list; ?>"><div id="<?php echo $up; ?>" class="tagBlockW" title="<?php echo $list; ?>"><?php echo "$val"; ?></div></td> <?php
        if($i==7){ $i=0;?>  </tr> <?php }?> 
        <?php }

        ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you certain that only things that are immediate children of the element with ID `tableTr` can have the class `tagSelected` applied?  If there is any element outside of `tableTr` with the class `tagSelected`, this script will fail.

Comment: try to remove child as `c.parentNode.removeChild(c)`, don't know why but i think it's safer :) Another thought: maybe this script interfers with something else

Comment: No, i dont have anything with the class of tagSelected, the html is just a php script populating the table, and then i have an onclick function which changes the class of the <td> from tagBlock to tagSelected. and now trying to remove them from the table leaving the rest.

Comment: c.parentNode.removeChild(c) worked :) !  could it of been because i had multiple <tr id="tableTr"> and was trying to call them ? .. not sure, but thanks guys

Comment: @Jason: You **must not** allow multiple elements with the same ID. It is not valid, and will break code in browsers. Also, it is really really bad to call the same selector in a loop. You should cache the selection outside the loop, the iterate the loop (preferably in reverse since you're removing nodes).

Comment: can you give a quick example of this for me please. Not sure what you mean by cache the selection then iterate loop. Ill change the same element id- no probs was just in my test page

Comment: @Jason: I'll add an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

- **Do not use duplicate IDs.**

It is not valid, and will give unexpected results. Either use a class, or make the IDs unique.

- **Do not do redundant DOM selection in a loop.**

DOM selection is an expensive operation. It should be done once, outside the loop, then cached.

- **There's no need to check for the `tagSelected` class inside the loop.**

You used `getElementsByClassName('tagSelected')`, so obviously they have that class.

---

It seems that you simply want to remove the elements with the given class.

```
  // Fetch all elements in the document with the class 'tagSelected'
var selectTag = document.getElementsByClassName('tagSelected');

  // Remove all of them.
while( selectTag[0] ) {
    selectTag[0].parentNode.removeChild( selectTag[0] );
}
```

The reason that `while( selectTag[0] ) {` works is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a "live" NodeList. This means that when an element is removed from the DOM, the list is updated.

So because we're removing all the elements, all we need to do is run the loop as long as there's something at index `[0]`.

Comment: guess i was over complicating it ... understand now. have removed the id from tr as it is not needed. Just tested - works perfectly. Thanks @RightSaidFred

Answer (score -1):

```
var p = document.getElementById('tableTr'); 
while(selectTag=document.getElementsByClassName('tagSelected')) {     
if(!selectTag[0]) {         
break;     
}
if(selectTag[0].className=="tagSelected")         
   var c =selectTag[0];          
   p.removeChild(c);     
   } 
}
```

First of all u have one error(might be) which is u dont have opening brace "{" after secound if condition.

You can rather do this actuly.

```
var p = document.getElementById('tableTr'); 
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('tagSelected')).length;i++)
{
     var c = selectTag[i];
     p.removeChild(c);

}
```

Comment: thnx. ended up using this with the c.parentNode.removeChild(c)

Comment: As I noted in the comment above, it is really really bad to do DOM selection in a loop. You do it once, and cache the result outside the loop. And your second example won't work.

Comment: It will? You have an extra `)` in the `for`, and you have no `selectTag` collection for `var c = selectTag[i];`. Anyway, the actual issue is OP's invalid code that reuses IDs.

Comment: Rather thn that sntex error it will work, as it will give collection cause of getElementsByClassName. it will give only selected elements and what is to be deleted. nyway thanx for sntex correction :) ;)

Comment: Yes `document.getElementsByClassName('tagSelected')` returns a collection, but you're not storing the collection anywhere! You're just using it to get the length. You need to reference the collection in a `selectTag` variable in order to do `selectTag[i]`.