# Remove child throws exception

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

This code throw me a strange exception. `Node "<span class="OrganisationOut"></span>" was not found in the collection` but when I check the outerHTML of span its `<span class="OrganisationOut">National Cheng Kung University</span>`. Why it try to remove different span?

```
doc = web.Load(urlTeams);

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[contains(@id,'Cell')]"))
{
    HtmlNode span = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span");
    lbResults2.Items.Add(span.InnerText);
    lbResults.Items.Add(node.RemoveChild(span).InnerText.Trim());
}
```

Comment: Do not do redundant DOM selection in a loop.

Comment: you mean the `HtmlNode span = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span");` part?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269590/removechild-node-was-not-found-cant-work-it-out see this

Comment: its different from what I do... i have a collection from nodes and then i loop through it to take the innerText of tr and the innerText of span.. I not loop through entire DOM..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting all spans recursively under the current node (that's what `//` means in XPATH), you may get a `span` that is not a child of `node`, but a grand child.

In this case the call `node.RemoveChild(span)` will fail as you see. What you want to do instead is `span.ParentNode.RemoveChild(span)`.

Comment: I did what you say but now lbResults and lbResults2 give same output

Comment: oh I solved it... instead of doing all in one line i should separate it... like this `span.ParentNode.RemoveChild(span); lbResults.Items.Add(node.InnerText.Trim());` instead of `lbResults.Items.Add(span.ParentNode.RemoveChild(span).InnerText.Trim());`